# Give multiple-stage plan exclusive access until completed

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, bamboo

We have three projects in Bamboo, each with one or two active plans, depending on how close we are to a release.  I've split up the plans into multiple stages to give us more flexibility, and concurrent builds are disabled.

If one project is building and a commit is made on a second project, the remaining plans "interleave", with one another.  For example, given two projects "m" (maintenance) and "n" (new development), and a set of plans (fetch-source, build-servers, build-clients, deploy), the stages might execute like this:

```
m:fetch-source
m:build-servers
    n:fetch-source
m:build-clients
    n:build-servers
m:deploy
    n:build-clients
    n:deploy
```

This causes both builds to run slower, and defeats one of our goals for splitting up the jobs into stages.  Is there a way to give one plan exclusive access until it's completed, and then run the next plan in the queue?  In other words, can I configure Bamboo to treat multiple stages as a single stage at the plan level?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of a way of doing this unless you specify through requirements and capabilities that only one agent can run that particular set of stages.

The only other way I can think of doing this would be to group a plan to a agent with the plugin here:

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.edwardawebb.bamboo-group-agent